# How do I queue jobs for when I have network?

Tags: android

I'm working on an app where I create entries in a database while offline. I need to be able to have the app push these entries to a web server when I get a data or WiFi connection, and then delete them from the queue, but not from the app's database. **I'm wondering if there are any libraries that already do this?** I'm willing to code my own if I need to, but I thought I'd ask on here and see if anyone's heard of anything.

Thanks!

Comment: If I may ask, why is this question being voted down?

Comment: There's nothing vague about this question. At all. Let me bold out the important parts for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if there is an existing library to do this. But I am also doing the same for my app by simply using a couple or java files. 
I use **broadcast receiver** to be notified whether there is network connectivity or not. If there is no network connectivity, i update and variable which i check before every network call. 
If the variable is positive i send the HTTP Request, else i queue it in a DB.

Everytime the network connection resumes(using the same broadcast receiver), I check the DB for pending requests and send them across and update the DB accordingly.

Comment: This sounds like exactly what I need to do, and if you haven't heard of any libraries that do it, then I'll just code it myself, I guess. Thanks!